# Linux command to find the differences between two files

Tags: linux

I have file1 that contains lines exactly the same as file2 BUT file 2 has more lines. I need to extract these additional line ONLY. I tried `diff` command but the output really long and I need just the additional lines. Can anybody help ?

Comment: I believe different will do what you want but I don't know the exact options. They should be able to help over at superuser

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/68786/88978

Comment: You can also use graphical tools like `meld`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `diff -w` it will ignore the all whitespaces.
Further, you can pipe your output to `more` this way you'll be able to view all the differences:

```
 diff -w file1 file2 | more
```

If you want a nicer display you can use the switch `-y` which will display two pages side-by side, and `-l` will add pagination:

```
diff -wyl file1 file2
```